# Cite does not work from review

Tags: bug, review, citation

When reviewing e.g. First Posts, the `cite` link is shown under the post. However, clicking it has no effect:

[image]

This might be the same bug which makes the `share` link unusable after the first review, but that only happens *after* the first review, and there at least the popup is shown for a little while. Here, nothing happens.

(I'm not sure if citing is really useful from the review queue, but in that case the link should not be shown altogether.)